# How to rewrite URL in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have searched the web for a solution to rewriting the URL.

I have tried to use `ThunderMain.URLRewriter` but it didn't map  the URL and when the link is requested i got a `404 resource not found` error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this UrlRewriter: http://urlrewriter.net/